# Apache2 Site Only Accessable at Machine's IP Address

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've got a Raspberry Pi broadcasting a wifi network, I have a 'Hello world' equivalent Python Flask application at /var/www/flask-dev.  When I connect to the network on my computer and point my browser at the Pi's IP address (192.168.0.10) the flask application turns up, however, I am trying to get it to display at http://my.webtool/. Any advice on how I could get the application to show up at http://my.webtool/ would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure the answer is going to be super simple, but I just haven't been able to figure it out.

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       pi-zero-arcade
127.0.0.1       unseen.arcade
192.168.0.10    my.webtool
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName my.webtool

    WSGIDaemonProcess webtool user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/flask-dev/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask-dev/webtool.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/flask-dev>
        WSGIProcessGroup webtool
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On

        Require all granted
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled only has my.webtool.conf inside it.

/var/www/flask-dev/webtool.wsgi

```
import sys

sys.path.append('var/www/flask-dev')

from webtool import app as application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you have three ways to achieve this:

1. DNS
2. Hosts file(s)
3. mDNS.

### DNS

You have two ways here - either a local DNS within your LAN, that replies authoritatively for `my.webtool`, or register a valid DNS name (such as `mywebtool.com`) at some registrar, and set up valid DNS for it.

Running a DNS server within your LAN will make the name available to anyone in your LAN, but not on the Internet. Such a nameserver may already be included with your router; many routers have some kind of nameserver, typically based on dnsmasq or unbound. Check your router for how to add names to it.

You can also set up a DNS server on Ubuntu, but every device on your LAN has to be configured to use that DNS server for it to work.

If you register a name with some registrar, create an A record that points to the IP of your Pi. Note that if it's a [RFC1918-IP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918), it will not work outside your LAN.

### Hosts file

On every host that shall access the service, you have to add

```
192.168.0.10    my.webtool
```

to `/etc/hosts` on most *nix OS, or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows.

### mDNS

mDNS is multicast DNS, and works within your local network. You cannot use `my.webtool`, as mDNS names *has* to end in `.local`.

To do this, you have to configure a mDNS responder on your Pi, that will reply to queries, and configure your clients to use mDNS as a lookup source.

On Ubuntu this is handled by `avahi`. I will not go into detail for this here, I suggest to make a new question if you need help with getting mDNS up and running. The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html) is a excellent resource for how to edit the configuration file , and is fairly detailed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a comprehensive answer, I greatly appreciate it.  I'll look into those and see what I can do.  I have dnsmasq on my Pi and will start by trying to use that.  It only needs to work within the LAN.

Comment: Be aware that dnsmasq also includes a dhcp server, so you may want to disable dhcp server on your router and use your pi as a DHCP server :)